# Which elements and ailments have the most vulnerabilities / resistances?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

In the Monster Hunter Field Guide, each monster has a vulnerability rating for each element and ailment, from 0 (high resistance) to 3 stars (high vulnerability).

[image: diablos-chart]

The picture above shows that the Diablos is very vulnerable to Ice and Paralysis (3-star), but very resistant to Fire (0-star / X).

It's best to have multiple weapons of different types so you can attack each monster most efficiently, so I'm not asking which element is "the best". But, if you wanted to focus on / prioritize certain weapons more than others, because of material limitations or tree structure, **which element / ailment types are large monsters most commonly vulnerable / resistant to?**

Comment: Focusing on a single element, while it sounds like a good idea, won't really help you in the long run.  If you're looking for a more reliable way to attack any monster, focus on raw damage, and ignore elements entirely.  Otherwise, prepping for the monster you want to fight is core to the gameplay loop.

Comment: Maybe a better frame for the question could be that you want to make a new elemental weapon for yourself and have the resources for only one - which element/status would be the best choice?

Comment: @Zodack Yeah, Thats a better way of putting it, but i figured it would get razzed for trying to ask which element was best or something. I was pretty explicit that I wasn't doing that, and yet it was the first comment. I hesitate to get any more specific but if you have a good edit in mind, have at it, no worries.

Comment: The question is based on a false premise; that each weapon uses the same materials. If you've been fighting ice monsters, you can make ice weapons. You're not going to be getting materials to make fire weapons. Using a numerical argument misses aspects of gameplay that invalidate element entirely. Amor skills, your current location, and most of all, your own skill, all affect this. Just saying, "most monsters are weak to ice" ignores all of it.

Comment: @Frank i am NOT saying to just use this element or that element, which is again EXPLICITLY stated in both question and answer.  This question is based on the premise that items *share* materials, which they do, if you look at the trees. So if you have two options to get to an ice weapon and a sleep weapon, and even though their numbers are comparable, you could read this and say hey, a lot of monsters hate ice, very few hate sleep. Handy information.

Comment: I disagree.  The information is useless in the grand scheme of things, and can actually be harmful, as it implies all monsters can be handled the same way.  Following this is just *asking* to get complacent.  Monster Hunter *rewards* proper preparation, and you're just dumbing it down to, "take this weapon".

Comment: @Frank You're obviously intent on misunderstanding the purpose of the information, but I don't think everyone else will. Each to his own I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TL;DR

Ice, Thunder, Paralysis, and Stun are the most common effects for monsters to be **vulnerable** to (3-star and 2-star ratings). If you only care which effects have the most *high vulnerabilities* (3-star), then you want to actually aim for Water, Thunder and Poison (more on that at the bottom). So, Thunder seems to be the statistical winner for vulnerabilities.

For effects to avoid, Fire, Water, and Blast are the most common effects for monsters to be **resistant** to (1-star / 0-star). I didn't catalog all the high resistances (0-star only) but I may add that later (or someone else is welcome to).

The numbers are pretty even depending on how you look at them, so this is not suggesting you completely devote yourself to, or completely ignore, any type of weapon. I personally just thought it was useful information.

---

*Note: This is only concerning [large monsters](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Large+Monsters)*

If you go through and tally up how many monsters have a **3-star or a 2-star vulnerability** to an element / ailment, here are the results:

*Elements*

- Fire: 11
- Water: 14
- Thunder: 18
- Ice: 21
- Dragon: 13

*Ailments*

- Poison: 19
- Sleep: 21
- Paralysis: 22
- Blast: 19
- Stun: 22

And if you tally up how many monsters have a **0-star or 1-star vulnerability** (which means they have a resistance to it):

*Elements*

- Fire: 16
- Water: 16
- Thunder: 12
- Ice: 8
- Dragon: 14

*Ailments*

- Poison: 10
- Sleep: 10
- Paralysis: 8
- Blast: 11
- Stun: 6

#### What does this mean?

When comparing vulnerabilities, **Ice and Thunder** will be the most effective elements across the greatest number of monsters. For ailments things are pretty even across the board, but **Paralysis and Stun** are statistically most effective, with Sleep in second place.

Comparing resistances, **Fire and Water** are the most common elements for monsters to be resistant to. For ailments, **Blast** is the leader, with Poison and Sleep tying for second place.

Taking things a little further, I personally don't consider a 2-star rating to be a true vulnerability, even though it's one less than a 3-star. So, I always go for the effect that has the 3-star rating if at all possible, just to be most damaging.

Taking that into account, it's more interesting to me to know which elements / ailments have the most **3-star** vulnerabilities, without taking into account the 2-star results. Here are those numbers:

*Elements*

- Fire: 5
- Water: 8
- Thunder: 8
- Ice: 4
- Dragon: 5

*Ailments*

- Poison: 8
- Sleep: 3
- Paralysis: 5
- Blast: 5
- Stun: 5

This changes the above results slightly, making **Water and Thunder** the leaders in elemental damage, and **Poison** the clear leader in ailments. It's interesting to note that Thunder is in the winner's circle for the 3-star-only comparison, as well as the 2-star + 3-star comparison.

Source: [monsterhunterworld.wiki](https://monsterhunterworld.wiki.fextralife.com/Large+Monsters)